# Multiple devise sessions, destroy one of them

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating a rails application where a user(care_giver) can sign in using devise. After this sign in the user gets a overview with all of the assigned Fitbit accounts. Here the CareGiver can sign in with one of these Fitbit accounts using omniauth. But when I want the CareGiver to sign out(destroy) the Fitbit session, the CareGiver always gets signed out aswell with the Fitbit session.

**Redirect user after session destroy**

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
 care_givers_client_overview_path
end
```

**In the view:**

```
= link_to 'Uitloggen', destroy_care_giver_session_path, class: "", data: { confirm: 'Weet u zeker dat u wilt uitloggen?' }, method: :delete
```

**The error im receiving:**

*undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass*

```
def client_overview
  @fitbits = FitbitUser.where(:care_giver_id == current_care_giver.id )
end
```

My question is how can i destroy just one session (Fitbit) without actually touching the CareGiver's session.

Comment: Can you get care_giver id?

Comment: Yes i can, but after the destroy link on the Fitbit page, care_giver_id will be nil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put `config.sign_out_all_scopes = false` in `devise.rb`. Devise standard signs out all scope's (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb, line 26).

Comment: Awesome. Found this after 2 hrs of grinding. Phew. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped! :)